# ffmpeg adjust contrast, show histogram

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to first adjust the contrast of a frame extracted from an mp4, then overlay the histogram of the resultant frame on top.  My command here does all of this, but also adjusts the contrast of the histogram itself.  Is there a single `ffmpeg` command that can do what I wish?

[image]

```
    ffmpeg -ss 3.5 -i in.mp4 -an -y -vf \
    "split=2[a][b],[b]eq=0.5:0:1:1:1:1:1,histogram=levels_mode=logarithmic:\
    components=1:level_height=100, [a]overlay,eq=0.5:0:1:1:1:1:1" \
    -vframes 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 3.5 -i in.mp4 -an -y -filter_complex \
    "eq=0.5:0:1:1:1:1:1,split=2[a][b];[b]histogram=levels_mode=logarithmic:\
    components=1:level_height=100[b];[a][b]overlay" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

Comment: bonus question: is there any way to adjust the opacity of the histogram using the split filter?  It's always showing 100%, even if I force with `:fgopacity=0.5:bgopacity=0.5`